# Unknown Publisher warning using Symantec EV Certificate

Tags: certificate, clickonce, code-signing, signtool, symantec

My company purchased an EV Certificate from Symantec to use for a software product we produce.  Specifically it is called: Symantec Class 3 Extended Validation Code Signing CA – G2.

We apply the Certificate to the execuatables and DLLs using signtool.exe, and this has accomplished our main goal of eliminating the SmartScreen warning during installation on Windows 8/8.1.

However, the install dialogs produced by our ClickOnce installer are showing:

***Publisher: Unknown Publisher***

We have tried everything we can think of to solve this including contacting Symantec Tech Support.  They have not been able to help us, and could only advise us to call Microsoft for help.  We thought asking here would take us further.

Has anyone else run across this problem?  Might anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Did you sign the manifest?

Comment: I am not doing anything explicitly to the manifest, no.  If I need to add that step to my process, would you know where I could find simple instructions how to do so?

Comment: I guess [this MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996418.aspx) will help you. If not, let me know.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with a Digicert EV Certificate, I posted a question in the msdn forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f3899e84-63e4-442d-b147-5372fda5597e/unknown-publisher-in-the-clickonce-installer-using-an-ev-code-signing-certificate?forum=winformssetup

Comment: You may want to look at this posting: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/89eed0e7-ca4f-4022-904e-00c95052a3c7/clickonce-windows-8-smartscreen-unknown-publisher-ev-certificate?forum=winformssetup.  I'm currently waiting for a response from the program manager of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

When using signtool try to use `/d` and `/du` options. I was having similar problems with activex installations and this helped me.

For more information please look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: I tried these and they didn't have any effect.  Still get the Unknown Publisher warning.

Comment: Is this ClickOnce installer also signed? How was it signed? Try to sign it using signtool with /d option. What I did with activex was sign all dlls, msi installer and cab file with signtool.

Comment: I don't think that the problem comes from signtool.exe, because the ClickOnce manifests files are signed with mage.exe (also in the Microsoft SDKs). In my case, the setup.exe and the executable are correctly signed but the ClickOnce manifests files aren't and causes this "Unknown publisher" in the ClickOnce installer.